# How to integrate generated SQL table in Spring MVC

Tags: sql, database, oracle, spring-mvc

so I have generated a very easy SQL table with the help of https://www.generatedata.com/

How do I stick/integrate the .sql file(scheme) to a basic Spring MVC project?

Comment: SO is not for how-to questions. Please have a look at [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You would want to create DAO classes as in this [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example).